# Number of free dynos running

Tags: web, heroku, web-deployment

So, after my research on stackoverflow and other portals, I have not found any answer to the below question.
I am using a free Heroku account without any kind of payments. If I run, say 2, applications on the free account, does it mean that I am using 2 dynos. Because I know that two dynos will consume double the dyno hours(If both the applications never sleep. I am aware of these basics of Heroku), and so this is a concern for me.